# Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework.SqlServer, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, asp.net5

I am using ASP.NET 5 and Entity Framework 6 (precisely 6.1.3), following this [link](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/data/entity-framework-6.html). Tried every different solution like

1. Scrapping of Version in appconfig
2. Adding `<dependentAssembly>`
3. Reinstalling EntityFramework 6 again using `Update-Package
   -reinstall EntityFramework`
4. Check EntityFramwork.SqlServer
5. Cleared %temp% and did clean build along with standalone rebuild

**I get error here**

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(CodeConfig))]    
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
public MyContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection") <-- error here
    {
    }
 }
```

But still couldn't resolve this error, any helpful links would be appreciated

> Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework.SqlServer, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"EntityFramework.SqlServer, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"

**Stack Trace**

```
at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TypeExtensions.CreateInstance[T](Type type, Func`2 exceptionFactory)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TypeExtensions.CreateInstance[T](Type type, Func`3 typeMessageFactory, Func`2 exceptionFactory)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DbConfigurationManager.<.ctor>b__1()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DbConfigurationManager.GetConfiguration()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.InternalConfiguration.get_Instance()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbConfiguration.get_DependencyResolver()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.InitializeLazyInternalContext(IInternalConnection internalConnection, DbCompiledModel model)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext..ctor(String nameOrConnectionString)
   at myproject.data.myprojectContext..ctor() in D:\Projects\Personal\myproject\myproject.data\myprojectContext.cs:line 12
   at myproject.data.Infrastructure.DatabaseFactory.Get() in D:\Projects\Personal\myproject\myproject.data\Infrastructure\DatabaseFactory.cs:line 9
   at myproject.data.Repository`1.get_DataContext() in D:\Projects\Personal\myproject\myproject.data\Repository.cs:line 28
   at myproject.data.Repository`1..ctor(IDatabaseFactory databaseFactory) in D:\Projects\Personal\myproject\myproject.data\Repository.cs:line 21
   at myproject.data.Repository.ProfileRepository..ctor(IDatabaseFactory databaseFactory) in D:\Projects\Personal\myproject\myproject.data\Repository\ProfileRepository.cs:line 9
```

**Web.Config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework.SqlServer, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="...." />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Could you try cleaning temporary files normally under `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files` and Clean Solution?

Comment: Also, try `right click solution → clean solution → and rebuild`

And also something I have encountered before was that multiple entries of the public key token had been added to my `app.config` when I had this error. Strange isn't it

Comment: The worst case could you remove it completely, and install again instead of reinstall?

Comment: In some cases I could fix errors like this by simply removing everything from the `packages` folder on disk (using Explorer), and then restoring the packages by enabling Package Restore (an option used to always retrieve missing packages on Build).

Comment: @Win yes did clear %temp% and did reinstall too

Comment: Could you please add entityFramework providers in your app.config?

Comment: @Krohn my gulp is triggered on clean so yes did rebuild, there are no multiple token on app.config

Comment: @uteist its added already

Comment: To point out the obvious, is that DLL in your execution directory?

Comment: @CathalMF yes its seperate dll

Comment: @brykneval Whats your directory structure and where is the EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll?

Comment: @CathalMF somewhat related project structure is on lower part of stacktrace that I posted. Its simple project.data, project.web . . .  entityframework.sqlserver on project.data

Comment: Do you have multiple refrences to the EntityFramework.SqlServer dll? Are they all using the same version?

Comment: @brykneval My bad, missed the link there. What about <dependentAssembly> section? Did you have bind redirection there? or just the assemblyIdentity?

Comment: @uteist both, I scrapped it coz question was getting unnecessarily long

Comment: @brykneval Running out of options here :) Had the same issue before and invariantProvider + `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />` had fixed it for me. Any chance that you have multiple projects in your solution and maybe one of the projects refer to old EF.dll / EF.SqlServer.dll ?

Comment: @brykneval I'm curious about this one. Any progress so far? Could you check your project(s) for references?

Comment: @uteist I have checked no references to earlier version, its a small project and now transferring to 4.5.1

Answer (score 0):

First check which version EF you are using. Check the your version.
If you want to upgrade your version you can manage EF upgrade from NuGet.

Go to your Project solution - > 'Manage NuGet packet for Solution', click 'Manage' on 'Entity Framework'.

Now, Check your app.config . Maybe here wrong version number. The name="entityFramework" should have the correct version number.

Other then this, you should try installing the nuget package for EntityFramework.SqlServer by using following command in package manager console.

> Install-Package EntityFramework.SqlServer -Version 7.0.0-beta6 -Pre

Answer (score 0):

The parameter of base (DbContext constructor) can be a `nameOrConnectionString`. See [DbContext(string)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.-ctor?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#system-data-entity-dbcontext-ctor(system-string)).
So you should add `name=` to the parameter string.

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(CodeConfig))]    
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext()
        : base("name=DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
}
```

See also this example: [Derived context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/workflows/existing-database#derived-context)